# Problema de organização do conteudo

Tags: html, css

Ola

Eu tenho quatro selects e cada select tem o seu determinado titulo, mas eu estou com um problema apesar de eu no HTML ter o titulo em cima do select e em baixo de um botão, o titulo do select aparece em cima do botão ao centro e eu gostava que esse titulo volta-se ao sitio dele, alguem sabe como resolver este erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<button id="filtroselects">
  <img src="/imagens/iconfiltro.png" height="40px" width="40px"> Filtros
</button>

<div id="escolha">
<form id="selectsfiltro">
    <h6>Faixa Etaria:</h6>
    <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">0-17</option>
        <option value="2">18-25</option>
        <option value="3">26-35</option>
        <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/> 
    <h6>Sexo:</h6>
    <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="5">Masc</option>
        <option value="6">Fem</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Recurso a arma:</h6>
    <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="7">Sim</option>
        <option value="8">Não</option>
    </select>


    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Localidade:</h6>
    <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
        <option ></option>
        <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
        <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
        <option value="11">Bragança</option>
        <option value="12">Braga</option>
        <option value="13">Porto</option>
        <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
        <option value="15">Viseu</option>
        <option value="16">Guarda</option>
        <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
        <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
        <option value="19">Leiria</option>
        <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
        <option value="21">Santarém</option>
        <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
        <option value="23">Évora</option>
        <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
        <option value="25">Beja</option>
        <option value="26">Faro</option>
        <option value="27">Açores</option>
        <option value="28">Madeira</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
 #filtroselects {
       background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.0);
       color: white;
       border: 0;
       cursor: context-menu;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
       margin-left: -8px;
       font-size: 25px;
       float: left;
       margin-top: 30px;

   }
```

Comment: Já tentou usar labels?

Comment: David sem seu CSS não da para te ajudar muito, pq se vc executar esse Snippet ai da sua pergunta vc vai ver que fica tudo certo, então o problema é no CSS e não no HTML, Edite sua pergunta e inclua o CSS tb sem ele não da para te responder

Comment: @hugocsl o unico css que tenho foi esse que la pus o resto dos ids sao usados com scripts para os selects e algumas funções funcionarem, isto só ficou assim depois de termos colocado umas funções para telemovel, mas supostamente so devia editar em telemovel, não existe nenhum codigo que eu possa por para que o titulo do select fique em cima do select automaticamente?

Comment: @Afonso não, eu tambem não sei o que é isso.

Comment: <div id="escolha"> Fechas esse div?

Comment: @Pbras Sim essa div so serve para fazer um script para telemovel não tem muito a ver com o select para computador, devo ter esquecido de fechar quando copiei o select para o site.

Comment: Ok, experimenta mudar o dysplay do ```<button id="filtroselects">```, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp sem usar o web inspector não sei qual o melhor para meteres ai mas deve de haver um que resolve esse problema, experimenta os seguintes, flex, inline, block, grid, só adicionar um ```style="display=XXX;"``` ai para exprimentar com esses valores, depois diga se algum desses ajudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já que vc falou que esse CSS é o único usado no documento, acredito que basta tirar o `Float:left` do CSS do `Button` que vai resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está certo! Obrigado!!

Comment: @DavidMv sem problemas meu caro!